# Should I be using bundle_green to connect to SQLite on a phone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently using this to connect to my phone's SQLite database:

[image]

Can someone explain to me how I can find out more about bundle_green, who created it, who maintains it and what it is?

Comment: Eric Sink maintains `SQLitePCL.raw` (https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw) and it contains the native SQLite libraries for 10+ frameworks|platforms (IMHO, this is an "invaluable" project for .Net, Mono and Xamarin)

Comment: Do you recommend I change to SQLitePCL.raw?  What are the differences?  Thanks

Comment: Same, read the bundle section: https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw#bundles